# Entity Framework Core Identity in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET framework application in which I am working on porting from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core 3 as a good midpoint in a port to .NET Core.

However, identity in Entity Framework Core is part of ASP.NET Core, and I have not found any information on using identity for EF Core in .NET Framework.

Is it possible to do this? What options would I have for identity in this configuration.

Comment: `identity` here means you want use `.NET Framework identity` in EF core?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Unless I am misunderstanding,  I would still need to use .NET Framework identity since the application is still an ASP.NET application.

Comment: The Microsoft document show that EF core 3.1 can support for .NET Framework 4.7.2, So i am not sure your version can fit it ....

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I am using EF Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.8 so it should be supported.